# Best practice architecture for server to server consistency

Tags: architecture, server, consistency

I'm working on a system where there is a server that gets requests from the UI (client) then it creates a call to another server which is communicating with an external web API.

The problem I'm facing is an inconsistency between the 2 servers because the external API facing server can fail to do actions with the external API sometimes it can fail after 20 minutes or so.

So the status can be

Server A sent request to Server be and got 200 ok
 - Status on server A can be ACTIVE or PENDING
Server B sends an API call and fails
 - Status on server B is now error

What is the best practice to tell server A that the action actually failed?

Answer (score 0):

Highly depends on client and server design.
If I understood you right, API call from Server B to external API (I call it C in the following text) is designed asynchronously:

```
 A ---------> B
 A <-- ACK -- B
              B ---------> C
              B <-- ERR -- C

(A <-- ERR -- B) 
^ that is your question
```

Depending on message communication, there are multiple possibilities. If you operate on REST calls, your acknowledgement from B to A could contain an operation ID and an endpoint where A could ask for the status of the operation:

```
{
    status: queued,
    operationId: 12345
    operationStatusUri: yourhost.com/api/queue/123456
}
```

The client could now use an A call to poll the status.

If you have some kind of message based architecture, you could push the error from B to A using a message bus system.